# How to support user polymorphism in Django without raw sql?

Tags: django

Subtitle: when the student becomes the teacher

Imagine two classes, Student and Teacher, that each inherit from User. None of these models is abstract. How to you modify an instance of student so that they can also be a teacher, without just dropping into raw sql and inserting the teacher record?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. You cannot have an instance of `student`that is also an instance of `teacher`. These two classes have a common ancestor, but they do not inherit from each other. Can you try to explain again what you are trying to achieve/

Comment: Could you have a `User` for a person (login), then if creating them as a student, also create the related `Student` record, likewise for teachers. Then if you want to be both, just create the other one for the same user. The harder part is probably context management in the application.

Comment: @KonstantinSchubert think of a grad student, who also teaches some class. This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve: a user who is both a student and a teacher.

Comment: @skywater In that case, inheritance isn't the right model for you. Because an object can only be of one type, not two. But you want the option to freeely add or remove the student property and the teacher property from your user. You should probably choose a pattern that favors composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to think about your design. Not in terms of Django, but generally.

If you have a User class, and a Student class and a Teacher class, then you can create instances of User, of Student and of Teacher. You cannot create an instance that is both a student and a teacher, *unless* you create a fourth class StudentTeacher that inherits from both Student and Teacher. This is a special case of multiple inheritance, called "diamond shape" inheritance and it is rarely a good idea.

Django does support inheritance for its models. If B inherits from A, and A isn't declared abstract to Django, then Django will create a table for A and a table for B with a foreign key to A and it will join the tables B and A if you access an instance of B.

But I don't think that Django supports *multiple* model inheritance, which you would need here. And even if it does, it will lead you into a world of pain.

The solution is, I think, to [favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Instead of creating `User`, `Student`, `Teacher` and `StudentTeacher`, you create `User`, `StudentRole` and `TeacherRole`.

Then, you can compose the user with the student role or the teacher role, or both. The user *has a* teacher role or *has a* student role.

In Django, you use a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) for this:

```
class User(Model):
    name = CharField()

class StudentRole(Model):
     user = OneToOneField(User, related_name='student_role')
     average_grade = FloatField()

class TeacherRole(Model):
     user = OneToOneField(User, related_name='teacher_role')
     age = IntegerField()
```

`And then you create objects like this:

```
user = User()
user.save()
student_role = StudentRole(user=user)
student_role.save()
teacher_role = TeacherRole(user=user)
teacher_role.save()
```

(Of course you can also use `StudentRole.objects.create` and so on.)

And you can use the object like this:

```
user.student_role.average_grade = 4
user.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
user = User.objects.get(whatever_id)
student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
teacher = Teacher.objects.create(user=user)
```

Here you have the same user having an instance in Student object and Teacher object.
But as pointed in a comment, a Student instance can't be a Teacher one. That's impossible. It's not about django.

Comment: The third line will throw an IntegrityError. But if you replace it with raw sql that creates the teacher record with user_ptr_id=user.id, you then get a student and teacher that both share the same ID, and user.student and user.teacher are both good instances of their respective classes.

Comment: Post your model in the question.

Comment: I suspect that the integrity error happens because the inheritance implicitly creates a One-To-One relationship between Student and User and Teacher and User. Therefore it doesn't allow two different objects (student and teacher) to refer to the same user.